# Magento 1.9 create category and product using SQL(MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento, orm

I need to add a new category and new product using SQL because I have a large product list (10000) and ORM is terribly slow.
So now I want to use direct database access to insert new categories and products but there are too many tables, for example, to insert a new category I want to know what column of what table should I fill?
Do you know some improvements to speed up the execution time of the script?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can look at how magmi does it:
https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git
it's known for being one of the fastest

category code:
https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git/blob/master/magmi/plugins/extra/itemprocessors/categories/categoryimport.php

but I'd suggest installing the importer and using it instead of reinventing the wheel